# How can I select specific items in a table based on a value in another table using LINQ Method syntax in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

**[Edit]**
I never got this to work and instead opted to use a viewmodel for all the information I needed.

**[Original]**
I have a table of Quotes with Services associated with it. Each quote also uses a specific Pricelist, identified with a PricelistID. (I've removed all extraneous properties from all classes for clarity.)

```
public class Quote {
   public uint QuoteID { get; set; }

   public uint PricelistID { get; set; }
   public Pricelist Pricelist { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }
}
```

A Service contains the Name of the service and references to Quotes and Pricelists.

```
public class Service {
    public uint ServiceID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Pricelist> Pricelists { get; set; }
}
```

A Pricelist is a many-to-many join table for a Service and a Price.

```
public class Pricelist {
    public uint PricelistID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Price> Prices { get; set; }
}
```

A Price contains the customer specific price.

```
public class Price {
    public uint PriceID { get; set; }
    public float CustomerPrice { get; set; }
    public uint PricelistID { get; set; }

    public Pricelist Pricelist { get; set; }
}
```

When displaying information about the quote I want to grab the price(s) for the service(s) based on the pricelist referenced via *Quote.PricelistID* but I'm not skilled enough in LINQ to figure out how to grab all this in one go.

I've looked around at other questions, here and elsewhere, but either the question wasn't similar enough or the answer wasn't complete enough.

I want to use the method syntax if possible as that's what I've been using up until now.

Or maybe this isn't possible at all with one query?

**[Edit to add example]**

Acme Inc has requested a quote for office cleaning, window cleaning, and yard cleaning.

Acme uses pricelist A:

```
Office cleaning - 100 USD
Windows cleaning - 150 USD
Yard cleaning - 300 USD
```

The Quote for Acme object would include a reference to three services and pricelist A.

Burple Inc has requested a quote for yard cleaning only. They use pricelist B:

```
Office cleaning - 300 USD
Windows cleaning - 450 USD
Yard cleaning - 600 USD
```

The Quote for Burple would include a reference to one service and pricelist B.

(The services are the same no matter the customer, only the prices change depending on the price list indicated in the quote.)

When a sales representative looks at a quote I want to grab all the information about the quote, services, and prices in one query and then display it.

Let me know if this helped at all or if you need more information. :)

**[Second edit, adding ERD]**

[image: ERD for all tables and relations]

Comment: Your models look a little bit strange, did you create them by hand or a tool did that? Maybe it would be better if you give some sample data to show what you really want. For example Services, it is both in Quote and PriceList. Many to Many PriceList seem wrong to me. Generally you don't need that at all.

Comment: A Price has a price list which has collections of services and its own prices, and services has a collection of quotes which have a collection of services and a pricelist also. I think the confusion here is the result of an unclear hierarchy of objects. Maybe if I studied this more it would make more sense but the circular compositions are head spinning. This data is in serious need of normalization

Comment: Ok, what object are you "starting" with? I can probably get you the LINQ that way. Are you trying to get this data out of a `Price` object?

Comment: @CetinBasoz - The models are created by hand, based on tutorials from Microsoft, but could very well be wrong.

Services has a relationship with both Quote and Pricelist - a Quote consists of services and a pricelist sets the prices for services, based on the customer the quote is for.

Many to many for the pricelist might be wrong but then I'm not sure how to link any service to any price.

Comment: @Narish - a Quote has multiple services, and a Service can belong to multiple quotes. To me that's a many-to-many relation and I'm not sure how to illustrate that relationship other than via collections but if there's a better way, I'm interested. :)

Quote is the parent object, it has services that has prices in a pricelist, with the specific pricelist determined by the attribute in the Quote object.

Comment: services.Where(t=>t.Pricelists.PriceListID == t.Quote.PricelistID).FirstOrDefault(); 
is something like this what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Kief Yes, but for all of the services so I don't think `FirstOrDefault()` will work? I also need the prices for each service from the Price model/table.